# How do I add a constraint to a subview of an instance of UIView without my app crashing?

Tags: swift, uiview

I have an instance of UIView in Swift to which I add a subview of an instance of UIImageView but I can't add a constraint to the UIImageView instance without my app crashing.

I have tried writing Swift 5.0 code in Xcode 10.2 and iOS 12.2 to set the constraint that the leading edge of the UIImageView instance be 50 away from the left edge of the UIView instance.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let sectionHeaderView : UIView = UIView()

    let sectionHeaderImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Flag - ENGLAND.png")!
    let sectionHeaderImageView : UIImageView = UIImageView(image: sectionHeaderImage)
    sectionHeaderImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let imageViewWidthConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sectionHeaderImageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sectionHeaderImageView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 40)
    imageViewWidthConstraint.isActive = true
    sectionHeaderImageView.addConstraint(imageViewWidthConstraint)

    let imageViewHeightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sectionHeaderImageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sectionHeaderImageView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 40)
    imageViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    sectionHeaderImageView.addConstraint(imageViewHeightConstraint)

    let imageViewLeadingConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sectionHeaderImageView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sectionHeaderView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50)
    imageViewLeadingConstraint.isActive = true
    sectionHeaderImageView.addConstraint(imageViewLeadingConstraint)

    return sectionHeaderView
}
```

I expect the instance of UIView containing the instance of UIImageView to be positioned 50 to the right of the instance of the UIView. Instead the app crashes in Xcode with the error message "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" in the file AppDelegate.swift.

Comment: You have to add the view to the hierarchy by calling `addSubview` before creating constraints between parent and child.

Comment: I have added ```sectionHeaderView.addSubview(sectionHeaderImageView)``` but it still crashes. And I get the error message ```A constraint cannot be made between a leading/trailing attribute and a right/left attribute. Use leading/trailing for both or neither.'```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let sectionHeaderView : UIView = UIView()

    let sectionHeaderImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Flag - ENGLAND.png")!
    let sectionHeaderImageView : UIImageView = UIImageView(image: sectionHeaderImage)
    sectionHeaderImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let imageViewWidthConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sectionHeaderImageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sectionHeaderImageView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 40)
    imageViewWidthConstraint.isActive = true
    sectionHeaderImageView.addConstraint(imageViewWidthConstraint)

    let imageViewHeightConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sectionHeaderImageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sectionHeaderImageView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0.0, constant: 40)
    imageViewHeightConstraint.isActive = true
    sectionHeaderImageView.addConstraint(imageViewHeightConstraint)

    let imageViewLeadingConstraint : NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sectionHeaderImageView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: sectionHeaderView, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 50)
    imageViewLeadingConstraint.isActive = true

    sectionHeaderView.addSubview(sectionHeaderImageView) // add subview first
    sectionHeaderImageView.addConstraint(imageViewLeadingConstraint)
    return sectionHeaderView
}
```

Comment: No it still crashes with the error message ```Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x2828fb100 "UIImageView:0x149e39d40.leading"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x2828fb180 "UIView:0x149e39890.trailing"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let sectionHeaderView = UIView()
    let sectionHeaderImage = UIImage(named: "Flag - ENGLAND.png")!
    let sectionHeaderImageView = UIImageView(image: sectionHeaderImage)
    sectionHeaderImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sectionHeaderView.addSubview(sectionHeaderImageView)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        sectionHeaderImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        sectionHeaderImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
        sectionHeaderImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sectionHeaderView.leadingAnchor, constant: 50),
        sectionHeaderImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sectionHeaderView.topAnchor, constant: 50)
    ])
    return sectionHeaderView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you must add image to parent view

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let sectionHeaderView: UIView = UIView()

    let sectionHeaderImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Flag - ENGLAND.png")!
    let sectionHeaderImageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(image: sectionHeaderImage)

        sectionHeaderImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        sectionHeaderView.addSubview(sectionHeaderImageView)

        let imageViewHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: sectionHeaderImageView,
            attribute: .height,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: .notAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 40
        )
        let imageViewWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: sectionHeaderImageView,
            attribute: .width,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: nil,
            attribute: .notAnAttribute,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 40
        )
        let imageViewLeadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(
            item: sectionHeaderImageView,
            attribute: .left,
            relatedBy: .equal,
            toItem: sectionHeaderView,
            attribute: .left,
            multiplier: 1.0,
            constant: 50
        )
        sectionHeaderView.addConstraints([
            imageViewHeightConstraint,
            imageViewWidthConstraint,
            imageViewLeadingConstraint
            ])
    }
    return sectionHeaderView
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yervand Saribekyan that works! Can you recommend a good online resource to learn about setting constraints programmatically in Swift? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah of course, see examples in Apple Documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html